# Меню и однотипные действия

Tags: c#, winforms

В каждой форме решения есть меню, оно абсолютно идентично на каждой форме. Есть ли необходимость копировать код кликов на него в каждую форму, или можно сделать по другому?

К примеру, в каждой форме у меня меню и код:

```
private void оПрограммеToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        About frm = new About();
        frm.Show();
    }
```

Можно ли его перенести куда-то в одно место и вызывать оттуда?

Answer (score 1):

Можно создать форму родителя, которая будет содержать общее меню и общие обработчики событий выбора пунктов меню. А потом от этой формы родителя наследовать все свои формы.

Answer (score 1):

Если на всех формах меню одинаковое, то используйте Frame. В нем создайте меню. Пропишите все что надо. А потом вставляйте его на каждую форму.